# Problema com instalação do Jetty no eclipse/STS

Tags: eclipse, plugin, jetty

Estou tentando instalar o plugin do jetty no eclipse/STS
e sempre da problema nessa maquina, instalei na minha e deu certo,
mas aqui que eu preciso para trabalhar nao consigo.(ja foi formatada)
já tentei pelo marketplace do eclipse,
já tentei instalar pelo windows>preferences>install>
já verifiquei sobre o erro na internet, falam para ir nas conecxões
colocar para manual ou direct e etc
já fiz tudo isso nada funciona!
não sei mais o que fazer, já baixei o plugin por fora joguei
dentro da pasta de pluggin do STS/eclipse.
já tentei instalar como archive local e apontar para o zip
enfim nada funciona!
alguém poderia me ajudar?
Tem algum subistituto ao jetty ?
porque dessa forma to desistindo de por ele aqui.
Já reinstalei o eclipse e o sts varias vezes até baixei a pasta do eclipse da minha maquina
e coloquei aqui e nao funciona o jetty de forma alguma.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

site que usei do Jetty.
name: Eclipse Jetty -
location: http://eclipse-jetty.github.io/update/

erro :Communication with repository at http://eclipse-jetty.github.io/update/content.xml.xz failed.
Communication with repository at http://eclipse-jetty.github.io/update/content.xml.xz failed.
Read timed out

Comment: Tentou instalar via marketplace http://marketplace.eclipse.org/node/581283#group-details ? O endereço /update parece não existir mais.

Comment: Sim, ja tentei pelo marketplace como tu falou... :/ e esse endereço realmente colocando no google diz que nao existe, "not found" porém instalando-se ele na minha máquina pessoal pelo mesmo jeito ai em cima, funciona, só nao funciona no notebook que trabalho. Ainda to com esse problema... instalei uma IDE de outra pessoa que tinha o jett ja instalado, peguei por zip só assim para funcionar. porque já baixei diversas IDE e acontece a mesma coisa.